# InputMismatchExeption when scanning double

Tags: java, methods, double

When i scan a 11.2 f.e. it'll say inputmismatchexception.

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    double u;
    double r;
    double i;

    calculateU(0, 0, 0);
}

public static void calculateU(double u, double r, double i) {

    System.out.println("Bitte Wert R in Ohm angeben: ");
    Scanner scanR = new Scanner(System.in);
    r = scanR.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Bitte Wert I in Ampere angeben: ");
    Scanner scanI = new Scanner(System.in);
    i = scanI.nextDouble();

    u = r/i;
    System.out.println("Spannung in V: " + u);
}
```

ive tried floats as well

Comment: You can use the same `Scanner` object twice.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 11,2 instead of 11.2
Normally using "." instead of "," would be correct, but I think it's because you are using a german terminal.